# Issues with selectedIndex?

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access

So I have this Select Case where it works when the selected index is 0, but if I change the index to 1, it doesn't. Currently the code is identical, the idea is that it will run different queries, but I need to get it working first.

Yes I plan on using parameterized queries when I get this portion of the program functioning correctly, until then I'm sticking with my generic concatenated query text, UNLESS it is specific to the issue.

So when the Index is 0 it runs the query fine, when the Index is anything other than 0 it doesn't work.

```
Select Case (cmbSearchBy.SelectedIndex)
        Case (cmbSearchBy.SelectedIndex = 0)
            Try
                'Sql = "SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE (((Devices.[Asset Number]) =" &  & "));"
                Dim SearchAsset As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtValue.Text)
                Dim AccessDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
                AccessDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE (((Devices.[Asset Number]) =" & SearchAsset & "));", dbConn)
                Dim AccessDataset = New DataSet
                AccessDataAdapter.Fill(AccessDataset, "Asset Query")
                MyDataGrid.DataSource = AccessDataset.Tables("Asset Query")
            Catch
                MsgBox("Please insert a valid Asset Number")
            End Try
        Case (cmbSearchBy.SelectedIndex = 1)
            Try
                'Sql = "SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE (((Devices.[Asset Number]) =" &  & "));"
                Dim SearchAsset As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtValue.Text)
                Dim AccessDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
                AccessDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE (((Devices.[Asset Number]) =" & SearchAsset & "));", dbConn)
                Dim AccessDataset = New DataSet
                AccessDataAdapter.Fill(AccessDataset, "Asset Query")
                MyDataGrid.DataSource = AccessDataset.Tables("Asset Query")
            Catch
                MsgBox("Please insert a valid Asset Number")
            End Try
```

I just don't understand why code that is the same isn't working.

Comment: If you are selecting case on SelectedIndex, shouldn't your case statements be Case 0 and Case 1 ?

Comment: Okay, so what's the difference between that and how it's laid out above?  It did make a difference, now I'm going to change some other things around and see how it goes with the other items to be queried.

Comment: `(cmbSearchBy.SelectedIndex = 1)` is a boolean expression, but the case sets up an integer test

Comment: Well, that was a lot simpler than I expected. It makes sense though.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: BTW vba IsNot VB.NET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to put the test variable in each `Case` statement; just the `Select` statement. The compiler will compare that expression to each expression listed with `Case`, in order, until it finds a match.

The expression `(cmbSearchBy.SelectedIndex = 0)` evaluates to `True` when the value is 0, which is also equal to 0. When the value is 1, `(cmbSearchBy.SelectedIndex = 0)` is `False` (-1), so it checks the next case. However, `(cmbSearchBy.SelectedIndex = 1)` = `True` = 0, BUT `cmbSearchBy.SelectedIndex` (which is what the `Select` command told the compiler to compare) = 1, and 0 does NOT equal 1, so the compiler looks for the next `Case` line. Since it doesn't find one, nothing happens.

Instead type:

```
Select Case cmbSearchBy.SelectedIndex
    Case 0
        'code
    Case 1
        'code
End Select
```

Comment: Good job explaining to the OP exactly why his code isn't working.